# Attribute error: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'value_counts'

Tags: python, pandas, imblearn

I am getting the following attribute error when I tried to rebalance the biased data:

```
'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'value_counts';
```

it seems that the line `y.value_counts()` gives the attribute error

**code:**

```
X = df.drop(columns=['type', 'quality'])
y = df['quality']

from imblearn.over_sampling import SMOTE

oversample = SMOTE(k_neighbors=5)
X, y = oversample.fit_resample(X,y)

y.value_counts()
```

Comment: [`SMOTE.fit_resample`](https://imbalanced-learn.org/stable/references/generated/imblearn.over_sampling.SMOTE.html#imblearn.over_sampling.SMOTE.fit_resample) returns "array-like of shape (n_samples_new,)" for `y`. If you want to use [`pandas.Series.value_counts`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) it will need converted back into a Series.

Answer (score 0):

An `ndarray` has no such attribute. Also, attributes don't need the `()`.